# Angular Dropdown when expanded is showing up at bottom of screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

[What the webpage looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7KTB.png)

So I am trying to make a dropdown but when the dropdown is clicked it displays not overlapping the other input, but at the bottom of the screen.

Here is the relevant chunk of HTML code:

```
                <div class="form-row">
                   <!-- Grid column -->
                   <div class="col-md-6">
                      <mat-form-field>
                         <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
                         <mat-select [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
                         </mat-select>
                      </mat-form-field>
                   </div>
                   <!-- Grid column -->
                   <!-- Grid column -->
                   <div class="col-md-6">
                      <!-- Material input -->
                      <div class="md-form form-group">
                         <input mdbInput type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4MD" placeholder="John's Law Firm">
                         <label for="inputPassword4MD">Firm Name</label>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                   <!-- Grid column -->
                </div>
                <!-- Grid row -->
```

This is the relevant part of the ts file:

```
toppings = new FormControl();
  toppingList: string[] = ['Extra cheese', 'Mushroom', 'Onion', 'Pepperoni', 'Sausage', 'Tomato'];
  constructor() { }
```

And finally, this is my app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import {MatButtonModule,MatIconModule} from '@angular/material';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';
import { ServicesComponent } from './services/services.component';
import { ScheduleComponent } from './schedule/schedule.component';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    ServicesComponent,
    ScheduleComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    ServicesComponent,
    ScheduleComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatSelectModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Can you provide the chunk of HTML code that shows how you are using the dropdown?

Comment: Or better still, reproduce it on stackblitz?

Comment: @AlmaniaM I copied the wrong html part in but I edited it

Comment: Is the console throwing some sort of error?

Comment: @Adrian - It looks right. The only thing I can think of is some CSS overriding the positioning. You might need to provide any CSS that could be messing with it or take provide a StackBlitz link.

Comment: @AlmaniaM https://github.com/apilkington2/pilkington-reporting here is a link to my repo I'm having a hard time replicating it in StackBlitz

Comment: @AlfredoZamudio no errors just a couple warnings

Answer (score 1):

You'll need an Angular material core theme in your styles.scss file. Just add this in styles.scss:

```
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

or whatever other themes you want. You'll need the core theme for components to act right and then you can create a custom theme if you don't like the core default colors.